# Godot "Invalid get index 'transform' (on base; 'NIL'). Error

Tags: godot, godot4

i was following some tutorial, was typiyng exactly as guys in tutorial was, but when i tried to run project i got "Invalid get index 'transform' (on base; 'NIL') error', and i really have no idea why

```
extends CharacterBody3D


const SPEED = 5.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = 4.5

@export var TILT_LOWER_LIMIT := deg_to_rad(-90.0)
@export var TILT_UPPER_LIMIT := deg_to_rad(90.0)
@export var CAMERA_CONTROLLER : Camera3D

var _mouse_input : bool = false
var _mouse_rotation : Vector3
var _rotation_input : float
var _tilt_input : float

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")

func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("exit"):
        get_tree().quit()
        
func _unhandled_input(event):
    _mouse_input = event is InputEventMouseMotion and Input.get_mouse_mode() == Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED
    if _mouse_input:
        _rotation_input = -event.relative.x
        _tilt_input = -event.relative.y
        print(Vector2(_rotation_input,_tilt_input,))
        
func _update_camera(delta):
    
    # Rotate camera using euler rotation
    _mouse_rotation.x += _tilt_input * delta
    _mouse_rotation.x = clamp(_mouse_rotation.x, TILT_LOWER_LIMIT, TILT_UPPER_LIMIT)
    _mouse_rotation.y += _rotation_input * delta
    
    CAMERA_CONTROLLER.transform.basis = Basis.from_euler(_mouse_rotation)
    CAMERA_CONTROLLER.rotation.z = 0.0
    
    _rotation_input = 0.0
    _tilt_input = 0.0
        
func _ready():
    Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED

func _physics_process(delta):
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta
        
    _update_camera(delta)

    # Handle Jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("move_left", "move_right", "move_forward", "move_backward")
    var direction = (transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized()
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
        velocity.z = direction.z * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, SPEED)

    move_and_slide()
```

here is the script and [scene tree if needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOgpW.png)

i checked my code for 3-rd time but couldnt see any issues, im sure that i made some dumb grammatic error, but again couldnt see where.
also if i remove everything that refers to CAMERA_CONTROLLER projects runs just fine, and CAMERA_CONTROLLER refers to Camera3D, and something from this, script just doesnt see,

i tried retyping script twice but the problem was still there, changing reseting Camera 3d position to 0 and moving it using only CameraController.

Comment: The error implies that `CAMERA_CONTROLLER` is not set, yet you say it refers to the `Camera3D`... Does it? You are exporting it, it should be set on the inspector. Anyway, from the picture, it seems that using an unique node name and setting the camera on ready would work.

Comment: unfortunatly. it didnt work, and the error was the same, and also what do you mean is should be set on inspector? like some setting of camera should be turned on, or it should show up when i inspect CameraController node?

Comment: According to the shared code, your `CharacterBody3D` exports `CAMERA_CONTROLLER` of type `Camera3D`, thus it should appear among the properties of the `CharacterBody3D` in the inspector when you select it. There you can set the `Camera3D` it should point to.

Comment: that actually helped me, camera started perfectly working after i assigned it in properties, thanks for helping me